# Circuitikz won't work

Tags: circuitikz

After lots of struggling to find a repository for downloading packages, since the one I used apparently needs "updates", I tried to compile a code using `circuitikz`, but the problem is that all the normal `tikz` commands work just fine, but the commands of `circuitikz` just won't work. I literally tried everything from uninstalling the package and reinstalling it again and again, manually and via MikTeX package manager, refreshed FNDB, all kinds of stuff, but it just won't work. Any clues to why and how to solve this problem?
Even basic things don't work

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[left=26mm, top=1.06in, right=26mm, bottom=1.06in]{geometry}
\usepackage{schemabloc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\begin{document}
\chapter[\'Etude syst\'ematique]{\'Etude syst\'ematique de quelques syst\`emes particuliers}
\section{Entr\'ees du syst\`eme}
On utilise l'entr\'ee impulsionnelle $\delta (t)$ et l'entr\'ee indicielle $u(t)$ pour d\'eterminer les caract\'eristiques temporelles de la r\'eponse. L'entr\'ee rampe unitaire $e(t)=t$ est utilis\'ee pour d\'eterminer les caract\'eristiques dynamiques du syst\`eme. Enfin, l'entr\'ee sinuso\"idale $e(t)=\sin (\omega _0 t)$ est employ\'ee pour d\'eterminer les caract\'eristiques fr\'equentielles de la r\'eponse. Si le syst\`eme est lin\'eaire et l'entr\'e est sinuso\"idale, la sortie sera aussi une sinuso\"ide \`a la m\^eme fr\'equence, mais d\'ecal\'ee de l'entr\'ee.
\section{\'Etude des syst\'emes du premier ordre}
\subsection{Mise en \'equation}
L'\'equation  la plus couramment rencontr\'ee est l'\'equation dif{}f\'erentielle:
\begin{equation}
T\dfrac{\mathrm d s(t)}{\mathrm dt} +s(t) =ke(t)
\end{equation}
ou $T$ et $k$ sont des constantes r\'eelles positives. $T$ est dite la \emph{constante du temps} du syst\`eme et $k$ est dite le \emph{gain statique} du syst\`eme.

En passant vers le domaine de Laplace:
\begin{equation*}
TpS(p)+S(p)=kE(p)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation}
\Rightarrow G(p)=\dfrac{S(p)}{E(p)}=\dfrac{k}{1+Tp}
\end{equation}
\paragraph{Exemple:}
Circuit RC
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
(0,0) to[R, l=$R$] (4,0);
  \end{center}
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of code that doesn't work, and report the error you get?

Comment: Edited the post accordingly. The error is that it doesn't recognize the command related to circuitikz (to[R, l=$R$])

Comment: Can you compile `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw 
 (0,0) to[R, l=$R$] (4,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}` and add the `.log` file to your question?

Comment: Well the weirdest thing just happened. Running and compiling this code on it's own is fine, but copying the SAME code into the document I am currently working on doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Can you then try to make a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) from your document? I.e. remove as much as you can from it (content and preamble), while still reproducing the error.

Comment: This is the error I got from the console output. That's the best I can do for now. ! Package tikz Error: + or - expected. See the tikz package documentation for explanation. Type H <return> for immediate help. ... l.38 (0,0) to[R, l=$R$] (4,0) ;

Comment: Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. - Called minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), which illustrates your problem.

Comment: Did you put circuitikz inside a tikzpicture?

Comment: The thing is that when I compiled the code given by the previous commenter it worked just fine. Copying the same code into my document (which is already fine) won't solve it. However, I will post the MWE that didn't go well in the original question above. Most of won't be related to the circuit itself.

Comment: Someone might be able to guess, but without a complete example I think it will be hard to answer.

Comment: Just updated the question with the MWE in it. Off topic, but really the people here are the best. Pros have no problem trying even to figure out the problem with a "noobie" like myself, even less helping and answering.

Comment: Sorry it's my fault that I forgot about it in the post, but really in my project it has that line of code and still the problem persists. Thanks for pointing this out to me though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have two issues in your *mwe*:

- french babel: `\usepackage[french]{babel}`, which overwrite some `tikz` internals. cure for that is add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` to document preamble
- `\end{center}` is before `\end{circuitikz}`

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}      % <---------------


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
(0,0) to[R, l=$R$] (4,0);
\end{circuitikz}
  \end{center}              % <---------------
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Majd just for your information. The reason you had an issue here is that the `french` option of `babel` makes the semicolon active. This means that it tries to add a little whitespace in front of it as it is common in french typography. In TikZ, this behavior is wrong of course and it got fixed in TikZ 3.0 by introducing the library, Zarko has shown you.

Comment: You sir are a life saver. It worked lile a charm. How could I have known this issue and how to fix on my own? I guess this piece of information is out of scope for a beginner such as myself.